# Getting a value from js into an sql variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I need some help figuring out how to get a value into an variable i use for a sql statement

I have the value from my js here

```
$('#journalName').on('click','.clickme',function(){
    alert($(this).attr('value'));

    var a=$(this).attr('value');
    $.post("../php/viewThisJournal.php",{val:a},function(data){});
    location.href="../subpages/viewThisJournalLogin.php" ;
});
```

and i need to get the value into the sql variable $selectedJournal that i use in my php file viewThisJournal.php which currently holds the value 27

```
$selectedJournal='27';
$loggedinuser=$_SESSION["email"];
$sql="SELECT ChapterTbl.heading, ChapterTbl.bodyText FROM ChapterTbl,JournalTbl WHERE (ChapterTbl.parentJournal='$selectedJournal') AND (JournalTbl.owner='$loggedinuser')";

try {
    $st = $conn->prepare($sql); 
    $st->execute();
    $rows=$st->fetchAll();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Server Error - try again!".$e->getMessage();
};

echo json_encode($rows);


?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use $_POST['val'] to retrieve the post variable named 'val'.

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work